# Adding Form in PostScript

Tags: c#, postscript

i have a c# application in which i want to insert a message in postscript file, so i created a form like

```
%%BeginResource: form myfrm
/myfrm 
<<
/FormType 1
/BBox [ 0 0 771 618] def
/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0] def
/PaintProc{pop
..........
}
>> /Form defineresource pop
%%EndResource
```

when i insert in page in page 
like this

```
newpath
gsave
3800 5025 translate
3221.875 2575 scale
myfrm execform
grestore
closepath
```

it gives me error when i view in ghostview. Any suggestion what i am doing wrong , previously what i was doing was create an image from text and insert in as EPS form it is working great but ps file size was increased.and also if possible can i insert a textbox in postscript.

after edit :-

```
/myfrm 
<<
/FormType 1
/BBox [ 0 0 771 618] 
/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0] 
/PaintProc{pop
0 0 moveto
(my name is ali) show
}
>> def

.....
.....
.....
newpath
gsave
3800 5025 translate
3221.875 2575 scale
myfrm execform
grestore
closepath
```

but no text is shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This PostScript code works for me:

```
%!
/C60 {/Courier findfont 60 scalefont setfont 30 700 moveto} def

/myfrm
   <<
     /Matrix [ 2 3 .1  2 0 0 ]  
     /PaintProc
        {
           /Helvetica findfont 24 scalefont setfont
           10 10 moveto
           (Your name is Haider) show
        }
     /BBox [ 0 0 450 100]
     /FormType 1
  >> def

C60 (Page 1) show myfrm execform showpage
C60 (Page 2) show myfrm execform showpage
C60 (Page 3) show myfrm execform showpage
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: something like it , how do u pass something like this             3800 5025 translate
3221.875 2575 scale     execform  if i have a ps file can i write it inside form?

Answer (score 3):

You have defined an instance of a Form resource, but you haven't loaded the resource before invoking execform. You either need to:

1) just define the form dictionary (but not store it as a resource)

```
/myfrm <<
/FormType 1
...
>> def
...
myfrm execform
```

2) load the resource before exec'ing it

```
/myfrm /Form findresource execform
```

Comment: can you please provide full example as both are giving error. What about textbox in postscript?

Comment: Perhaps you could quote the error(s) you are experiencing ? I don't know what you mean by 'textbox in postscript'.

Comment: draw a rectangle(bounding box) and write text within that box. Actually i have a converter htmltops and want to insert that ps generated by the tool multiple times in postscript , and sorry i forgot  (def) at the end and now there is no error but nothing is showing (see my question)

Comment: Possibly nothing is showing because you have a string to show `(my name is...)` defined, but don't have a font defined...